# The matching algorithm for hashing passwords

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, hash, hashcode

So my question is :

How does hashing algorithms actually check if passwords match because they generate a new password every time.

Let's suppose I have a password "***hello***"
And it's **becrypt** hash is "***$2a$10$8MJRrpBJ.L.9eO5pOQgdx.B3vmGZ5gOmdnWYJsMMJjZjZGhulBg7y***"
So next time when I match the login password and this hashed password how they tell if they are equal or not.

In simple how it matches both passwords what's the logic behind it.

Comment: They don't generate a password, they generate a hash. And yes, the hash is the same every time if the password is the same.

Comment: In PHP, the `password_hash` function automatically generates salt that is used for hashing so that hashing the same string twice gives different output. This salt is stored towards the beginning of the output format. In older versions of PHP you could manually specify the salt, and if you did, and reused it, the hashes would be the same: https://3v4l.org/JoUjh#v5.6.40